# WSO2 API Manager Get User list

Tags: wso2

Hi I am trying to export the list of users that have signed up for an API key using Carbon but can't seem to figure out where to do this. I have tried accessing the h2 database (the WSO2Carbon_DB as well as the APIDB, however, there is no user information stored in these tables - at least I can't find them.

Answer (score 0):

While going through directly in the APIM database, you may not be bale to find it,because tables are connected with constraints. But check the following tables; which contain the entries you needed

```
 IDN_OAUTH_CONSUMER_APPS,IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN,AM_SUBSCRIBER , AM_APPLICATION
```

Comment: Thanks Ratha, but the only schema I seem to have access to (thats showing up) is INFORMATION_SCHEMA and it's tables. The tables you mentioned above are not visible. Note, I am using the h2-1.3.171.jar server to access the database.

Comment: You should connect to APIMDB( HOME\repository\database\WSO2AM_DB) You are connecting to wrong DB. Use wso2carbon s username/password

Comment: Hi Retha, thats the database I am connecting to (with the INFORMATION_SCHEMA) and not getting results.