# WSO2 API Manager 4.2.0 - How to query a list of all registered devportal users?

Tags: wso2-api-manager

**Problem**

We are using WSO2 API Manager 4.2.0 with Resident key manager (not WSO2-IS).

As platform administrators, is it possible to query the full list of all registered users (including name, organization, email) ?

**Testing**

From the management console, we can view the list of user names and we can search using any of the individual claims associated with the user profiles.
This returns a list of the user names, but we have to look in each individual user name and profile for the associated user information.

Is it possible to query a list of all user information (claims) from the management console?

**Research**

I found a question from 2013 [wso2-api-manager-get-user-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16732397/wso2-api-manager-get-user-list)
This answer suggests querying the APIMDB database tables IDN_OAUTH_CONSUMER_APPS, IDN_OAUTH2_ACCESS_TOKEN, AM_SUBSCRIBER , AM_APPLICATION.

From querying our APIMDB, I can view a list of users from apim_db.AM_SUBSCRIBER table - but not the user profile information.
Is this stored in APIMDB? If so, are there any standard queries to join the relevant tables to retrieve the user profile information?

This old question is also relevant with an answer suggesting to write a client to access the user profile information.
[wso2-api-manager-subscriber-email-are-not-in-am-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29414575/wso2-api-manager-subscriber-email-are-not-in-am-database)
using [wso2-admin-services](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/wso2-admin-services/)

The API-M product APIs do not appear to support any user information queries [WSO2 Docs - product-apis](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/product-apis/overview/)
The Micro Integrator documentation includes management API for interacting with users for MI [WSO2 Docs - working-with-management-api/#get-users](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/observe/mi-observe/working-with-management-api/#get-users)

Are there equivalent user information admin APIs for API-M?

Any suggestions, most welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User profile information can be found in the shared_db database.

Table `shared_db.UM_USER` provides list of registered users.

Table `shared_db.UM_USER_ATTRIBUTE` contains the profile details, such as `givenName`, `surname`, `mail`, `organizationName`, etc.